# Is 'to gleam above char' an idiom?

Tags: idioms, literature

There is a phrase in *Almayer's Folly* by Joseph Conrad which seems to me an idiom, but I can't find it is. Here is an excerpt from the story with the phrase in question in bold:

Lingard, a rich merchant, has just asked the main character to marry his daughter, and he is evaluating the prospects of seizing the fortune of Lingard through this marriage.

> The consideration, the indolent ease of life - for which he felt himself so well fitted - his ships, his warehouses, his merchandise (old Lingard would not live for ever), and, crowning all, in the far future **gleamed above char**, where, made king amongst men by old Lingard's money, he would pass the evening of his days in inexpressible splendour.

I think it is clear that 'gleamed above char' is expressing that what follows next in the paragraph is the most precious thing to him about that future, just as the contrast of a flash of bright light over charcoal.

Is this an idiom or did Conrad just make it up?

Comment: Maybe this question is more suitable for _English Language & Usage_?

Comment: It might work on either site. Honestly, I suspect it's a typo in the source, as it seems extremely strange.

Comment: @NathanTuggy It's true. It's a typo. I just found here http://www.altheim.com/lit/almayer.html that the original says: _and, crowning all, in the far future gleamed like a fairy palace the big mansion in Amsterdam, that earthly paradise of his dreams, where, made king amongst men by old Lingard's money,_

Comment: Conrad's actual sentence: _"The consideration, the indolent ease of life—for which he felt himself so well fitted—his ships, his warehouses, his merchandise (old Lingard would not live for ever), and, crowning all, in the far future gleamed like a fairy palace the big mansion in Amsterdam, that earthly paradise of his dreams, where, made king amongst men by old Lingard’s money, he would pass the evening of his days in inexpressible splendour."_ Where "char" came from, only some incompetent OCR technician knows.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it concerns a typo in a cheapo print edition of the work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There seems to be some discrepancy in texts.

Your original cited text

> for which he felt himself so well fitted - his ships, his warehouses, his merchandise (old Lingard would not live for ever), and, crowning all, in the far future **gleamed above char**, where, made king amongst men by old Lingard's money, he would pass the evening of his days in inexpressible splendour.

Alternative text

> [for which he felt himself so well fitted—his ships, his warehouses, his merchandise (old Lingard would not live for ever), and, crowning all, in the far future gleamed like a **fairy palace the big mansion in Amsterdam, that earthly paradise of his dreams**, where, made king amongst men by old Lingard's money, he would pass the evening of his days in inexpressible splendour](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Page:Almayer%27s_Folly.djvu/18)

which is identical to [Transcribed from the 1915 T. Fisher Unwin Ltd. edition by David Price](https://www.gutenberg.org/files/720/720-h/720-h.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Just as it has been noted in the comments, it seems it is a very strange error in the edition I am reading. My edition is: *Almayer's Folly & The Rover* by Joseph Conrad, Wordsworth Classics, 2011, **ISBN-13**: 978-1840226645.
Based on [this version](http://www.altheim.com/lit/almayer.html) and [this](https://www.gutenberg.org/files/720/720-h/720-h.htm), the original text would be:

> The consideration, the indolent ease of life—for which he felt himself so well fitted—his ships, his warehouses, his merchandise (old Lingard would not live for ever), and, crowning all, in the far future **gleamed like a fairy palace the big mansion in Amsterdam, that earthly paradise of his dreams**, where, made king amongst men by old Lingard’s money, he would pass the evening of his days in inexpressible splendour.

Maybe he imagines that mansion in Amsterdam because his mother *bewailed the lost glories of Amsterdam* when he was young, as it is narrated before in the story.

And this doesn't contain any strange fake-looking idiom.

Comment: If you want to read useful and accurate versions of works in the public domain, visit Project Gutenberg (_Almayer's Folly_ is **[here.](http://www.gutenberg.org/files/720/720-h/720-h.htm)**) Cheap and shoddy editions of public domain works are a scam to take your money. If I were you, I'd return the thing to Amazon and demand a refund. If you want a real book in your hands, visit Powell's or A Libris and find an old print edition.

Comment: @P.E.Dant I actually purchased it at a book stand at a bus station. I don't mind if it has some errors, it will be very interesting to exercise my knowledge of English with an extra-hard Conrad... he is really hard to read even without errors!

Comment: This isn't just an error. It's as if you bought a print of Davinci's _Mona Lisa_ in which the lady's eyes are replaced by hockey pucks. Heaven knows what other elisions are in the book.